How I can loop through the immediate (non-hidden) children of a key in pgfkeys?
I want to define the .code for a pgf key so as to do something useful with each of the immediate children of that key which do not begin with a dot. For example:
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

% Define some keys
\pgfkeys{/thing-to-define/foo/.code={Foo}}
\pgfkeys{/thing-to-define/bar/.code={Bar}}
\pgfkeys{/thing-to-define/baz/.code={Baz}}

% Calling `/thing-to-define' should call the code for each immediate
% subkey (which does not begin with a dot) in a useful way (here,
% printing them as a list). This is the manual way to do that:
\pgfkeys{/thing-to-define/.code=
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/foo}
  \item \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/bar}
  \item \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/baz}
  \end{itemize}
}

% But I want an automated way. I imagine something like this:
% \pgfkeys{/thing-to-define/.code=
%   \begin{itemize}
%     \pgfforeachchild{/thing-to-define}{%
%     \item \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/#1}}
%   \end{itemize}}
 
\begin{document}

% This does what I want (but not in the automatic way I want)
\pgfkeys{/thing-to-define}

\end{document}

How can I do this programatically?
TIA

PGFkeys doesn't keep track of all the subkeys. There's a hierarchy but it can't be traversed. You could define your own handlers that would do the same as .code and .style but also add the defined key to a list but that could get messy with all the different ways. (.append code does nearly the same as .code if the keys wasn't defined previously.)

A few seemingly related Qs: 1, 2, 3, 4. Also PR#1286.
